# Screen components get squished when keyboard is opened flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a custom tile and a dialog box that contains some components, it has an icon and text which are transitioned from the tile, so the main problem is that when i click on a field inside of the dialog, it opens the keyboard, the keyboard generates a renderflex error which is easily solved by wrapping the error causing widget with the `SingleChildScrollView` but the problem arises when a widget like squishes the the dialog's container: the following video demonstrates what i am saying:

https://youtu.be/f-ZXHKygoJM

Error Log:

```
Reload already in progress, ignoring request
Reloaded 1 of 971 libraries in 853ms (compile: 173 ms, reload: 284 ms, reassemble: 250 ms).
D/InputMethodManager(30094): showSoftInput() view=io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView{3275d02 VFE...... .F...... 0,0-1080,2400 #1 aid=1073741824} flags=0 reason=SHOW_SOFT_INPUT
I/AssistStructure(30094): Flattened final assist data: 472 bytes, containing 1 windows, 3 views
D/InputConnectionAdaptor(30094): The input method toggled cursor monitoring on
D/InsetsController(30094): show(ime(), fromIme=true)

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 90 pixels on the bottom.

The relevant error-causing widget was
Column my_dialog.dart:88
You can inspect this widget using the 'Inspect Widget' button in the VS Code notification.
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#70131 relayoutBoundary=up4 OVERFLOWING
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

**my_dialog.dart**

```dart
// ignore_for_file: override_on_non_overriding_member

import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:smooth_like_flutter/components/service_field.dart';
import 'package:smooth_like_flutter/dialog_visibility.dart';

class AlignedDialogRoute extends PageRoute<void> {
  AlignedDialogRoute({
    super.settings,
    this.padding = EdgeInsets.zero,
    this.alignment = Alignment.center,
    required this.heroTag,
    required this.iconHeroTag,
    required this.textHeroTag,
    required this.builder,
  }) : super(fullscreenDialog: false);

  final EdgeInsets padding;
  final Alignment alignment;

  final String title = 'Followers';
  final double priceOfOne = 0.25;

  final quantityController = TextEditingController();
  final linkController = TextEditingController();
  var totalPrice = ValueNotifier<double>(0);

  /// The tag used to match the Hero transition widgets.
  final String heroTag;
  final String textHeroTag;
  final String iconHeroTag;

  /// The builder will create the widget that we want to show in the dialog.
  final Widget Function(
    BuildContext,
    Animation<double>,
    Animation<double>,
  ) builder;

  @override
  Widget buildPage(
    BuildContext context,
    Animation<double> animation,
    Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
  ) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                isDialogVisible = false;
              });
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: double.infinity,
              child: BackdropFilter(
                filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Hero(
              tag: heroTag,
              child: Container(
                height: 450,
                width: 280,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 1.5),
                    color: Colors.grey[100],
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 350),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Hero(
                      tag: iconHeroTag,
                      child: const Icon(
                        Icons.group_rounded,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        size: 40,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Hero(
                      tag: textHeroTag,
                      child: Material(
                        type: MaterialType.transparency,
                        child: Text(
                          title,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 5,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        ValueListenableBuilder(
                          valueListenable: totalPrice,
                          builder: (context, value, child) {
                            return Text(
                              value.toString(),
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700]),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 22,
                          height: 22,
                          child: Image.asset('assets/images/coin.png'),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                    AnimatedOpacity(
                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                      curve: Curves.easeInOutExpo,
                      opacity: checkDialog(isDialogVisible),
                      child: MyServiceField(
                        type: TextInputType.number,
                        controller: quantityController,
                        hint: 'Quantity',
                        onChange: (fieldData) {
                          var fieldNum = int.parse(fieldData);
                          totalPrice.value = fieldNum * priceOfOne;
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    MyServiceField(
                      type: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      controller: linkController,
                      hint: 'Link',
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 49,
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);

                        setState(() {
                          isDialogVisible = false;
                        });

                        showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return AlertDialog(
                                icon: const Icon(
                                  Icons.error_outline,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                ),
                                title: const Text("Notice"),
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                contentTextStyle:
                                    const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                content: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    ConstrainedBox(
                                      constraints:
                                          const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 300),
                                      child: const Text(
                                        "Your order has been placed and will be completed within 2 to 10 Hours.",
                                        style: TextStyle(),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                actions: [
                                  Center(
                                      child: GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                    },
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: Container(
                                        width: 200,
                                        height: 50,
                                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                                Radius.circular(10))),
                                        child: const Center(
                                            child: Text(
                                          'Ok',
                                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                        )),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ))
                                ],
                              );
                            });
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: 200,
                        height: 50,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30))),
                        child: Center(
                          child: ConstrainedBox(
                            constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 100),
                            child: const Text(
                              'Place Order',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get opaque => false;

  @override
  bool get barrierDismissible => true;

  @override
  Color? get barrierColor => Colors.black54;

  @override
  String? get barrierLabel => "Dialog dismissal barrier";

  @override
  bool get maintainState => true;

  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => const Duration(milliseconds: 500);
}

checkDialog(bool isDialogVisible) {
  double opacity;

  if (isDialogVisible) {
    opacity = 0.0;
  } else {
    opacity = 1.0;
  }
  return opacity;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways by which you can solve this problem.
use  resizetoAvoidBottomInset.

```
return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset : false,//you have given it as true
      body: YourWidgets(),
    );
```

Using scrollable containers.(you would've probably tried that)

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        ),
        child: IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              // CONTENT HERE
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Try the first one it should work fine hopefully.